# “Ascent" or "descent" in the context of ancestry?

Tags: word-choice, difference

[Ascent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ascent):

> 3 : a going back in time or upward in order of genealogical succession

[Descent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/descent):

> 1 : a : derivation from an ancestor

Which should I use to refer to someone who has a, let's say Chinese, origin:

- a person of Chinese **descent**, or
- a person of Chinese **ascent** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **descent** for this. We say that a person *descends from* their ancestors, or that a person *is descended from* their ancestors. A person's *descent* refers to their ancestral line as a whole.

> I am a person of Chinese descent.

You could also use "ancestry" or "heritage" as close synonyms. The latter emphasizes the cultural influence over the genealogical influence.

The only place I've heard **ascent** used in any genealogical sense is to refer to the evolutionary or sociological progress of a species or civilization, as in "the ascent of Man." This is just a fancier way of saying "the *rise* of Man."